# How to change the caret color of basic angular material native select?

Tags: css, sass, angular-material, material-design, angular-material2

I have implemented a basic native select from Angular Material. In this I want to change the caret color of select to green.

HTML :

```
<mat-form-field >
     <select matNativeControl >
          <option> A </option>
          <option> B </option>
          <option> C </option>
     </select>
</mat-form-field>
```

CSS :

```
.mat-form-field.mat-focused {
        .mat-form-field-ripple {
            display: none;
        }
        .mat-form-field-required-marker {
            color: green;
        }
    }

.mat-form-field {
   .mat-form-field-underline {
        background-color: green;
    } 
}

.mat-form-field.mat-form-field-invalid {
    .mat-form-field-ripple {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

Cannot figure out how to change the caret color to green in native select element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Default state

```
.mat-form-field-type-mat-native-select .mat-form-field-infix::after {
    color: green;
}
```

Use `!important` for focus color as well

Or use this

```
.mat-form-field-type-mat-native-select.mat-focused:not(.mat-form-field-invalid) .mat-form-field-infix::after{
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Awais, that worked in the default state. But when the select field is in focus then still the color sets to theme color. Any suggestions on how to change the color on focus of native select also.

Comment: change or you want that same color?